# Adding blank page where text ends on an odd page

Tags: vba, ms-word

We are using a Duplex printer and we want Summary and Royalty to start on a new page.

Summary is always one page, means we need to insert a blank page after this page.

There is another section i.e. Royalty, if Royalty finishes on an odd page number then we need to add a blank page.

My Code is:

```
Sub Test()
    InsertSectionBreaks "S U M M A R Y             "
    InsertSectionBreaks "R O Y A L T Y             "
End Sub


Sub InsertSectionBreaks(FindText As String)
    Dim FindRange As Word.Range, SectionRange As Word.Range
    Dim Found As Boolean

    Set FindRange = ActiveDocument.Content

    ' Find next section based on text, insert odd page section break just before
    FindRange.Find.ClearFormatting
    With FindRange.Find
        .Text = FindText
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Found = .Execute
    End With

    Do While Found
        'avoid adding a section break at beginning of document
        If FindRange.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) > 1 Then
            Set SectionRange = FindRange.Duplicate
            With SectionRange
                .Expand wdParagraph
                .Collapse wdCollapseStart
                .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakOddPage
            End With
        End If
        FindRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Found = FindRange.Find.Execute
    Loop
End Sub
```

But this is throwing the last line of page to blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the page break is part of the same paragraph as the last line of the page and the first line of the next page.

Using the code below will work.

```
Sub Test()
  InsertSectionBreaks "S U M M A R Y             "
  InsertSectionBreaks "R O Y A L T Y             "
End Sub

Sub InsertSectionBreaks(FindText As String)
  Dim FindRange As Word.Range, SectionRange As Word.Range
  Dim Found As Boolean

  Set FindRange = ActiveDocument.Content

  ' Find next section based on text, insert odd page section break just before
  FindRange.Find.ClearFormatting
  With FindRange.Find
    .Text = FindText
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    Found = .Execute
  End With

  Do While Found
    If FindRange.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) > 1 Then
      Set SectionRange = FindRange.Duplicate
      With SectionRange
        .Expand wdParagraph
    'move start of range until we get the page break
    .MoveStartUntil Cset:=Chr(12)
    .Collapse wdCollapseStart
    'add a new paragraph to separate the page break
    .InsertParagraph
    'move the range to include only the page break and replace it with a section break
        .Move wdCharacter
        .MoveEnd wdCharacter
        .Delete wdCharacter
        .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakOddPage
      End With
    End If
    FindRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Found = FindRange.Find.Execute
  Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need to insert the correct even/odd section breaks and it will automatically beginn the next section on a even or odd page. So you will never have to care about it.

For example if you have

> ```
> Section 1
>
> --- Even Page (section break) ---
>
> Section 2
> ```

Then *Section 2* will **always** start on a even page, no matter if *Section 1* ended even or odd.

[image]

See [Insert a section break](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-section-break-eef20fd8-e38c-4ba6-a027-e503bdf8375c).

Comment: I'm not creating these document myself. these comes from outer resources and have hundreds of pages. so i was trying to do it using Macro

Comment: Same procedure just need to find the positions where the section breaks need to be inserted. Don't insert blank pages.